# Linker Command Failed after updating cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, cocoapods

I had a project that was working fine and I decided to update cocoapods.  I ran 
 `pod install` after cocoapods updated, and now I'm getting this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lStripe
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I know this is a common cocoapods error/problem.  I've scoured the internet for the last 12 hours trying every possible solution.  Things I've done:

1. Made sure I'm opening the workspace
2. Reinstalled cocoapods
3. Downgraded cocoapods to a previous version (to 0.33.1)
4. Ran `deintegrate` and removed cocoapods
5. Reinstalled cocoapods again
6. Made sure **Build Active Architecture Only** is set to `NO` on both Pod and Target
7. Tried many variations for `Other Linker Flags` (see below for current setup)
8. My **Framework Search Paths** and **Library Search Paths** each start with `$(inherited)`

**Other Linker Flags**

```
$(inherited)
-framework
"CoreGraphics"
-framework
"Foundation"
-framework
"MobileCoreServices"
-framework
"Security"
-framework
"SystemConfiguration"
```

Sometimes, with the above Linker Flags, if I rerun `pod install` I get a bunch of arm64 errors which can only be solved by adding this to the linkers:

```
-l"Pods-Buyer-AFNetworking"
-l"Pods-Buyer-Stripe"
-l"Pods-Buyer-RKNotificationHub"
-l"Pods-Buyer-RKDropdownAlert"
-l"Pods-Buyer-SVProgressHUD"
```

I've also tried combinations of adding/removing this from the Linker Flags:

```
-ObjC
-lc++
-all_load
```

And finally, here's my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'Buyer' do

pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1'
pod 'Stripe'
# pod 'PaymentKit'
pod 'RKNotificationHub'
pod 'RKDropdownAlert'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
# pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']

end

target 'BuyerTests' do

end
```

I've also followed all of the steps on the CocoaPods Guides Troubleshooting page (specifically 'Using the CocoaPods Project' > Step 4).  That didn't change anything.

Is there anything I'm missing? This is driving me crazy...  I'm at wits end.  Any advice or things I'm missing would be really appreciated! (Oh and I'm running the latest Xcode version)

Thank you all in advanced!

Comment: Any news on this?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: If you manually edit the other linker flags once, CocoaPod can never effect it since it only generate a xcconfig file for Xcode. See [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3274#issuecomment-98391704)

Comment: Anybody have answer how to solve this issue? Also having same problem